# Limit Characters in Double

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I make a double appear with only two decimal places? Current code is as follows (but of course, it's showing a lot of decimal places):

```
    tipPercentDbl = 20;//tipPercent as Dbl
    tipDbl = (totalDbl * (tipPercentDbl/100));//tip as Dbl
    tip.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tipDbl];
    tipPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tipPercentDbl];
    totalWithTipDbl = (totalDbl+tipDbl);
    totalWithTip.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", totalWithTipDbl];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
tipPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tipPercentDbl];
```

to this

```
tipPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", tipPercentDbl];
```

Comment: If you want to have exactly two decimals even if the value has 'no digits after the dot' `%.2f` will do the job just fine. For example: `stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",(double)8` will output **8.00**. Perhaps you mean the opposite: if you *don't* want trailing zeros to be outputted on whole numbers?

Comment: @lxt: You are right. I mixed something up. I deleted this part.

Answer (score 2):

You want `%.2f`:

```
tip.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", tipDbl];
tipPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", tipPercentDbl];
// ...
totalWithTip.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", totalWithTipDbl];
```

Format specifiers take the form of:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

where `.precision` in the case of `f` specifiers means the number of digits to be printed after the decimal point.